# Openshift Online Starter: Cannot access deployed app

Tags: openshift, openshift-3, openshift-online

Did a basic build and deploy of a git repository

https://github.com/jboss-openshift/openshift-quickstarts.git

The external route for application is create and it's not accessible there.

cmd: oc get services gives me the below output.

I am not sure what's going wrong. I have tried to debug using the documentation but have not been successful.

[screenshot of oc get services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgqe9.png)

Comment: Which application did you build from https://github.com/jboss-openshift/openshift-quickstarts.git? Which template did you use to create the app?

Comment: I built the complete repository assuming I would be able to access them with paths.

Comment: What cluster are you on? Have you used ``oc rsh`` to access the container and used ``curl $HOSTNAME:8080`` to see if your application is responding? Certain Online Starter clusters are having issues which a resolution is still in progress.

Comment: FWIW,  Im on the US west 2 servers and they are very problematic. After deploying my app it takes about 5 minutes before it is accessible online.

Comment: If you build from a template (s2i) you should config the CONTEXT_DIR for the subdir of the repo you want to build and deploy in the final container.